# NFS Mount /home - best practice

Tags: mount, fstab, nfs

I have a computer lab with 10 Ubuntu 16.04 LTS machines set to mount the `/home` partition from a CentOS NFS Server on the network.

On the server side, the `/etc/exports` file contains the following mount options: `rw,no_root_squash`.

My problem is that sometimes, mostly when users log in or log out, the whole client machine freezes and the only way to unfreeze it is to hit the `reset` button. On the clients side, I just used `defaults` for the mount options.

I suspect I should be using different mount options on both sides and was wondering what are the best ones for mounting the `/home` partition...

Comment: How do you mount /home .. and with what options ?

Comment: As I have pointed out in my question....